# How can I export to excel when creating an application that works in the browser for Lightswitch?

Tags: silverlight-5.0, visual-studio-lightswitch, lightswitch-2012

How can I export to excel when creating an application that works in the browser for Lightswitch?

Answer (score 1):

There are some libraries which you can use to export from a browser application. Try out [Aspose](http://www.aspose.com), for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free extension for LightSwitch, called the [Office Integration Pack](https://officeintegration.codeplex.com/), that allows exports to Excel.

Beth Massi explains about using it:

- [New and Improved Office Integration Pack Extension for
  LightSwitch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2012/07/18/new-and-improved-office-integration-pack-extension-for-lightswitch.aspx)
- [Fun with the Office Integration Pack Extension for LightSwitch](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2011/09/22/fun-with-the-office-integration-pack-extension-for-lightswitch.aspx)